# facebook connect - automatically login

Tags: iphone, session, facebook

I want my iphone app automatically logs on to Facebook so that the user only once have to log on Facebook(not at every startup!). I need this feature, because I want to built in a friends highscore and a post-function and it would be annoying always to log in for checking the high score. One example what I mean is the app "Doodle Jump". When you start the program you are automatically logged in.

Once the user logs in for the first time on facebook, my program will asked for the "extended permission" from the user, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Also when I got the extended permission to a specific user, how can I use the extended features? For example when I use FBStreamDialog for posting a post the user has to be logged in. How can I post with the extended permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer: I can simply resume the session with [session resume] and the user does not have to log in every time.